# FTP image display in Android WebView

Tags: android, webview, ftp

Hey I'm struggling to get a tiff image downloaded from an **FTP** site to display in a `WebView`. After entering in the url in the format             imageView.loadUrl("ftp://username:password@ftpsite/path");

(and the url is able to successfully download an image in ie or chrome)

I get an error message saying **net::ERROR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME**. Does **FTP** not work in `WebView`? What else could the problem be?

(I later tried just downloading from the ftp site to the app but the image is `.tiff` and that opened up a whole new can of worms so I'm back to trying to use `WebView` instead of `ImageView`)

Edit: updated url with the path I actually use, I sloppily typed it in before :/

Comment: i think webview has no support for ftp, nor tiff formatted image files.

Comment: hey you wouldn't happen to be able to point me in a direction where you found/heard/read that, cause I've been reading that in a lot of places, but its never is documented everywhere

Comment: you can always check the source of [android](https://github.com/android). I did not see any ftp related code in the source. Also webview uses the common bitmap, canvas, paint, picture and drawable libraries, which has no support for tiff files. you can use _Apache Commons Net_ (simply add jar file as a library) for ftp connectivity, download tiff to device and convert it to jpeg/png (with another lib maybe). but converting tiff to another format is resource intensive and will cost you cpu,memory usage probably move your app up in "battery usage" screen.